# Seeking picture of original OU logo in Hebrew

Tags: history, kashrut-kosher, modern-times

It seems the OU (Orthodox Union) logo of today had a predecessor:
"Prior to Heinz sporting the OU logo that is recognizable today, the Loose-Wiles Biscuit Co sold their kosher crackers where a **complex seal featured the OU insignia in Hebrew**."
Source: https://aish.com/heinz-baked-beans-are-an-integral-part-of-our-jewish-american-history/

What did that Hebrew logo look like?

Comment: Probably similar (and if I recall, it's a complicated logo) to the one on these crackers endorsed by Yossele Rosenblatt: https://jewishaction.com/content/uploads/YOSSELER2.jpg -- sorry, need to find a higher-def picture.

Comment: From Jewish Action, Fall 2003: *Rosenblatt provided an endorsement for Sunshine Kosher Crackers and Cookies on the back cover of the sheet music for his new arrangement of “Keili Keili” (undated). When traveling, he writes, they are “a veritable lifesaver for me” and they are served in every Jewish home he visits. Below Rosenblatt’s signature are details of the kosher certification provided by the OU.*  https://jewishaction.com/jewish-world/people/standing-room-remarkable-career-cantor-yossele-rosenblatt/

Comment: Is this on-topic?

Answer (score 3):

This is the best resolution I was able to find for the seal of דער יוניאן אוו ארטאדאקס דזשואיש קאנגרעגיעשנס אוו אמעריקא (the Union of Orthodox Jewish Congregations of America) on that product:

[image]

It is from an advertisement for Sunshine Kosher Crackers on p. 8 of Der Morgen Journal, Feb. 7, 1927⁩:

[image]

You may find this interesting as well from p. 5 of Der Tog, Sep. 20, 1935:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://issuu.com/jewishaction/docs/low_res_winter_22/2?ff&experiment=last-page) website seems to have an original picture of the sunshine crackers and the original logo
[image]

In that same issue in the link above, [on page 74](https://issuu.com/jewishaction/docs/low_res_winter_22), item 3, has a different original logo, however it is not in Hebrew

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a reproduction from the Sunshine Kosher Cookie advertisement. It is actually in Yiddish, not Hebrew. Enjoy!

[image: Original OU logo in Yiddish]

Comment: Translation please?

Comment: @YehudaW Outer circle: under the supervision of the Union of Orthodox congregations. Center: of the United States of America

Comment: Saying this is Yiddish is a big stretch. It uses the Yiddish spelling for “America” and to some degree “Orthodoxim”, but everything else is Hebrew.

Comment: @ezra Shavuah tov. If you look at the context from their advertising, it’s clear that they are appealing to the Yiddish speaking community. Often, in the context of Torah and halachic communications, they mix Hebrew with Yiddish. But to my knowledge, not in the opposite direction. Things exclusively Hebrew/Torah are only in Lashon HaKodesh. Not sure what you are trying to emphasize. Only blessings.